# Encrypting large files using RSA and AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA384

Tags: c#, cryptography

I developed an application that stores large files. Those files are stored in plain text. Now the project owner wants those files be encrypted on storage, he wants confidentiality, integrity, and authenticity.

The application is written in C# using .NET Framework 4.8. There are no authenticated encryption stream cyphers in .NET Framework 4.8, so I need to create my homemade solution. I'm not a crypto guy, so I'm not sure if the solution is secure enough.

I have a secret RSA key pair acting as the master key. then I do the following to encrypt the source plain text file into the encrypted destination file and to do the opposite:

```
using HkdfStandard;
using System;
using System.Buffers.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace StreamEncryption
{
    public sealed class StreamEncryptor : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly RSA rsa;

        const int MAC_LEN = 48;
        const int HMACK_KEY_LEN = 64;
        const int AES_KEY_LEN = 32;
        const int AES_IV_LEN = 16;
        const int SALT_LEN = 32;
        const int INFO_LEN = 8;
        const int IKM_LEN = 64;
        const int PLAIN_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 64 - 1;
        const int CIPHER_BUFFER_SIZE = PLAIN_BUFFER_SIZE + 1 + MAC_LEN + SALT_LEN + INFO_LEN;

        public StreamEncryptor(RSAParameters parameters)
        {
            this.rsa = new RSACng();
            rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);
        }

        public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (IsDisposed) return;
            IsDisposed = true;
            rsa.Dispose();
        }

        static Aes CreateAesCbc256(byte[] ikm, byte[] salt, byte[] info)
        {
            var aes = Aes.Create();
            if (aes.KeySize != AES_KEY_LEN * 8) aes.KeySize = AES_KEY_LEN * 8;
            if (aes.Mode != CipherMode.CBC) aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            if (aes.Padding != PaddingMode.PKCS7) aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            var keys = Hkdf.DeriveKey(HashAlgorithmName.SHA384, ikm, AES_KEY_LEN + AES_IV_LEN, salt, info);
            var key = new byte[AES_KEY_LEN];
            Array.Copy(keys, 0, key, 0, AES_KEY_LEN);
            var iv = new byte[AES_IV_LEN];
            Array.Copy(keys, AES_KEY_LEN, iv, 0, AES_IV_LEN);
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;
            return aes;
        }

        static byte[] GenerateRadomNumber(int size)
        {
            using (var generator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                var randomNumber = new byte[size];
                generator.GetBytes(randomNumber);
                return randomNumber;
            }
        }

        static byte[] Concatenate(byte[] a, byte[] b)
        {
            var result = new byte[a.Length + b.Length];
            Array.Copy(a, 0, result, 0, a.Length);
            Array.Copy(b, 0, result, a.Length, b.Length);
            return result;
        }


        static int AesEncrypt(Aes aes, byte[] input, int inputOffset, int inputCount, byte[] output, int outputOffset)
        {
            using (var transform = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                int bytesWritten = 0;
                int blocks = inputCount / transform.InputBlockSize;
                int finalInputSize = inputCount - blocks * transform.InputBlockSize;
                if (blocks > 0)
                {
                    bytesWritten = transform.TransformBlock(input, inputOffset, blocks * transform.InputBlockSize, output, outputOffset);
                }
                var finalOutputBlock = transform.TransformFinalBlock(input, inputOffset + bytesWritten, finalInputSize);
                Array.Copy(finalOutputBlock, 0, output, outputOffset + bytesWritten, finalOutputBlock.Length);
                bytesWritten += finalOutputBlock.Length;
                return bytesWritten;
            }
        }

        static int AesDecrypt(Aes aes, byte[] input, int inputOffset, int inputCount, byte[] output, int outputOffset)
        {
            using (var transform = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
            {
                int blocks = inputCount / transform.InputBlockSize;
                int blockBytes = (blocks - 1) * transform.InputBlockSize;
                int bytesWritten = 0;
                if (blockBytes > 0)
                {
                    bytesWritten = transform.TransformBlock(input, inputOffset, blockBytes, output, outputOffset);
                }
                var finalOuputBlock = transform.TransformFinalBlock(input, inputOffset + (blocks - 1) * transform.InputBlockSize, inputCount - blockBytes);
                Array.Copy(finalOuputBlock, 0, output, bytesWritten, finalOuputBlock.Length);
                bytesWritten += finalOuputBlock.Length;
                return bytesWritten;
            }
        }

        private static byte[] emptyBlock = new byte[0];

        static void ComputeHash(HMACSHA384 hmac, byte[] input, int inputOffset, int inputCount, byte[] output, int outputOffset)
        {
            hmac.TransformBlock(input, inputOffset, inputCount, null, 0);
            hmac.TransformFinalBlock(emptyBlock, 0, 0);
            Array.Copy(hmac.Hash, 0, output, outputOffset, hmac.Hash.Length);
        }

        private static (byte[] aesikm, byte[] hmacKey) CreateKeys()
        {
            var ikm = GenerateRadomNumber(IKM_LEN);
            var salt = GenerateRadomNumber(SALT_LEN);
            var info = GenerateRadomNumber(INFO_LEN);
            var keys = Hkdf.DeriveKey(HashAlgorithmName.SHA384, ikm, IKM_LEN + HMACK_KEY_LEN, salt, info);
            var aesikm = new byte[IKM_LEN];
            Array.Copy(keys, 0, aesikm, 0, IKM_LEN);
            var hmacKey = new byte[HMACK_KEY_LEN];
            Array.Copy(keys, IKM_LEN, hmacKey, 0, HMACK_KEY_LEN);
            return (aesikm, hmacKey);
        }

        public void Encrypt(Stream clearSource, Stream cipherDestination)
        {
            var cipherBuffer = new byte[CIPHER_BUFFER_SIZE];
            var clearBuffer = new byte[PLAIN_BUFFER_SIZE];
            var (aesikm, hmacKey) = CreateKeys();
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA384(hmacKey))
            {
                var header = Concatenate(hmacKey, aesikm);

                var cipherHeader = rsa.Encrypt(header, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA384);
                cipherDestination.Write(cipherHeader, 0, cipherHeader.Length);

                var headerSignature = rsa.SignData(header, HashAlgorithmName.SHA384, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
                var signatureChunk = new byte[rsa.KeySize / 16];

                Array.Copy(headerSignature, 0, signatureChunk, 0, signatureChunk.Length);
                var encryptedSignatureChunk = rsa.Encrypt(signatureChunk, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA384);
                cipherDestination.Write(encryptedSignatureChunk, 0, encryptedSignatureChunk.Length);

                Array.Copy(headerSignature, signatureChunk.Length, signatureChunk, 0, signatureChunk.Length);
                encryptedSignatureChunk = rsa.Encrypt(signatureChunk, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA384);
                cipherDestination.Write(encryptedSignatureChunk, 0, encryptedSignatureChunk.Length);

                long chunkNumber = 1;

                while (true)
                {
                    var clearBytesRead = Read(clearSource, clearBuffer, 0, clearBuffer.Length);
                    if (clearBytesRead < clearBuffer.Length) chunkNumber = -chunkNumber;
                    var salt = GenerateRadomNumber(SALT_LEN);
                    byte[] info = new byte[INFO_LEN];
                    BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt64BigEndian(info, chunkNumber);
                    using (var aes = CreateAesCbc256(aesikm, salt, info))
                    {
                        var cipherBytes = AesEncrypt(aes, clearBuffer, 0, clearBytesRead, cipherBuffer, MAC_LEN + SALT_LEN + INFO_LEN);
                        Array.Copy(salt, 0, cipherBuffer, MAC_LEN, SALT_LEN);
                        Array.Copy(info, 0, cipherBuffer, MAC_LEN + SALT_LEN, INFO_LEN);
                        ComputeHash(hmac, cipherBuffer, MAC_LEN, cipherBytes + SALT_LEN + INFO_LEN, cipherBuffer, 0);
                        cipherDestination.Write(cipherBuffer, 0, cipherBytes + MAC_LEN + SALT_LEN + INFO_LEN);
                    }
                    if (chunkNumber < 0) return;
                    chunkNumber++;
                }
            }
        }

        static void RequiredRead(Stream stream, byte[] data)
        {
            int remainingBytes = data.Length;
            while (remainingBytes > 0)
            {
                var bytesRead = stream.Read(data, data.Length - remainingBytes, remainingBytes);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    throw new EndOfStreamException("Unexpected end of stream");
                }
                remainingBytes -= bytesRead;
            }
        }

        static int Read(Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            int remainingBytesToRead = count;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            while (remainingBytesToRead > 0)
            {
                var bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, offset + totalBytesRead, remainingBytesToRead);
                remainingBytesToRead -= bytesRead;
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                if (bytesRead == 0)  break; 
            }
            return totalBytesRead;
        }

        public void Decrypt(Stream encryptedSource, Stream clearDestination)
        {

            var cipherMsgLength = this.rsa.KeySize / 8;

            var encHeader = new byte[cipherMsgLength];
            RequiredRead(encryptedSource, encHeader);
            var header = this.rsa.Decrypt(encHeader, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA384);

            var signedData = new byte[cipherMsgLength];

            var cipherSignatureChunk = new byte[cipherMsgLength];
            RequiredRead(encryptedSource, cipherSignatureChunk);
            var signatureChunk = this.rsa.Decrypt(cipherSignatureChunk, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA384);
            Array.Copy(signatureChunk, 0, signedData, 0, signatureChunk.Length);

            RequiredRead(encryptedSource, cipherSignatureChunk);
            signatureChunk = this.rsa.Decrypt(cipherSignatureChunk, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA384);
            Array.Copy(signatureChunk, 0, signedData, signatureChunk.Length, signatureChunk.Length);

            if (rsa.VerifyData(header, signedData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA384, RSASignaturePadding.Pss) == false)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Header signature validation failed");
            }

            var hmacKey = new byte[HMACK_KEY_LEN];
            var aesikm = new byte[IKM_LEN];

            Array.Copy(header, 0, hmacKey, 0, HMACK_KEY_LEN);
            Array.Copy(header, HMACK_KEY_LEN, aesikm, 0, IKM_LEN);

            var cipherBuffer = new byte[CIPHER_BUFFER_SIZE];
            var plainBuffer = new byte[PLAIN_BUFFER_SIZE];
            var storedHmac = new byte[MAC_LEN];
            var calculatedHmac = new byte[MAC_LEN];
            var salt = new byte[SALT_LEN];
            var info = new byte[INFO_LEN];

            long chunkNumber = 1;
            bool isCompleted = false;

            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA384(hmacKey))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int bytesRead = Read(encryptedSource, cipherBuffer, 0, CIPHER_BUFFER_SIZE);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        if (isCompleted == false)
                        {
                            throw new EndOfStreamException("Unexpected end of stream");
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (isCompleted)
                    {
                        throw new CryptographicException("Some data has been externally appended to the file");
                    }
                    
                    if (bytesRead < MAC_LEN + SALT_LEN + INFO_LEN) throw new EndOfStreamException("Unexpected end of stream");
                    Array.Copy(cipherBuffer, 0, storedHmac, 0, MAC_LEN);
                    ComputeHash(hmac, cipherBuffer, MAC_LEN, bytesRead - MAC_LEN, calculatedHmac, 0);
                    if (storedHmac.SequenceEqual(calculatedHmac) == false)
                    {
                        throw new CryptographicException("Message authentication code validation failed");
                    }
                    Array.Copy(cipherBuffer, MAC_LEN, salt, 0, SALT_LEN);
                    Array.Copy(cipherBuffer, MAC_LEN + SALT_LEN, info, 0, INFO_LEN);
                    var storedChunkNumber = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt64BigEndian(info);
                    if (storedChunkNumber < 0)
                    {
                        storedChunkNumber = -storedChunkNumber;
                        isCompleted = true;
                    }
                    if (storedChunkNumber != chunkNumber)
                    {
                        throw new CryptographicException("File chunks are not in proper sequence");
                    }
                    using (var aes = CreateAesCbc256(aesikm, salt, info))
                    {
                        var plainBytes = AesDecrypt(aes, cipherBuffer, MAC_LEN + SALT_LEN + INFO_LEN, bytesRead - MAC_LEN - SALT_LEN - INFO_LEN, plainBuffer, 0);
                        clearDestination.Write(plainBuffer, 0, plainBytes);
                    }
                    chunkNumber++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The complete working solution is in [GitHub](https://github.com/jesuslpm/stream-encryption).

Is this code secure enough? What best practices am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Just a few quick finds:

- `static byte[] GenerateRadomNumber(int size)`

  You have a typo here.
- `static Aes CreateAesCbc256(byte[] ikm, byte[] salt, byte[] info)`

  You are using `Aes.Create()` which returns the desired cryptographic object as expected. What you didn't took into account is that there are some properties which are set to a default value, like `Mode` and `Padding`. Well guess what, these default values are just two of the values you are checking for.

  Speaking of checking some values, the code would be much easier to read if you just set these properties to your desired values without bothering about their former values. Removing the checking and also the setting of the default values again will lead to

  ```
    static Aes CreateAesCbc256(byte[] ikm, byte[] salt, byte[] info)
    {
        var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.KeySize = AES_KEY_LEN * 8;

        var keys = Hkdf.DeriveKey(HashAlgorithmName.SHA384, ikm, AES_KEY_LEN + AES_IV_LEN, salt, info);
        var key = new byte[AES_KEY_LEN];
        Array.Copy(keys, 0, key, 0, AES_KEY_LEN);

        var iv = new byte[AES_IV_LEN];
        Array.Copy(keys, AES_KEY_LEN, iv, 0, AES_IV_LEN);

        aes.Key = key;
        aes.IV = iv;
        return aes;
    }
  ```

  As you see, with a little bit vertical spacing inserted as well, the code is now much easier to read.

Comment: I'm checking for CBC mode, KeyLength and Padding because the documentation doesn't tell anything about the default values. May be I'm a bit paranoid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes.create?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Which is why, as indicated in the answer, it is much better to set them to specific values. It makes any auditing process easier as well, and it shows a deliberate choice.

Answer (score 3):

## crypto primitives

The review context mentions "confidentiality" and a lack of specialized expertise.

```
using HkdfStandard;
```

This led me immediately to reading the 2010
[rfc5869](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5869)
description of this building block.
It speaks of speed, of stretching low-entropy inputs,
and of increasing attacker's cost via iterating
with for example the 2000
[rfc2898](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2898) PKCS #5 spec.

For client applications that need a PBKDF to
stretch a low-entropy human memorable pass phrase,
I will usually recommend the 2015 contest winner
[argon2id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).
It deliberately imposes both cycle and RAM costs
on an attacker.
Here, we appear to have "enough" source entropy,
so perhaps such concerns aren't relevant.
I *am* sad there's no comment motivating the choice
of one particular primitive over another, and
nothing explicitly calling out the input entropy.

I do see that we're tacking on per-file salt
of 256 bits, which is an excellent match for
the "confidentiality" requirement. Good.

## key management

In your world-readable RSA
[key pair](https://github.com/jesuslpm/stream-encryption/blob/main/rsa_key_pair.xml)
file I see you are publishing the public key parameters:

```
  <Modulus>
  <Exponent>
```

Alas, I see that you reveal these, as well:

```
  <P>
  <Q>
  <DP>
  <DQ>
  <InverseQ>
  <D>
```

Please understand that "pair" in this context refers to
"public + private" key parameters.
To achieve the stated "confidentiality" requirement,
it is of the utmost importance that you *not*
disclose private key parameters to unintended individuals.

Roll a new key, and re-encrypt any existing files.

## key handling procedures

I am sad to find no advice, in OP or in the GitHub repo,
on recommended procedures for handling keying material,
including periodically expiring and re-rolling new keys.
This tends to be the Achilles heel of any deployed crypto system.
Pay careful attention to user education,
so folks understand what they should and shouldn't do.

## typo

```
        const int HMACK_KEY_LEN = 64;
```

Sorry, not following there.

We probably want to rename this 512-bit quantity as `HMAC_KEY_LEN`.

The consistent `_LEN` suffix is very nice; I thank you.

## buffer length

```
        const int PLAIN_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 64 - 1;
```

Ok, sixty-four KiB minus 1.

Why the minus 1?

I'm not getting the motivation.
On some systems I/O is able to take advantage of power-of-two sizes.
A kernel buffer might receive a 64 KiB prefix of giant file,
and then kernel **re-maps** buffer pages in the
[MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)
to give them away to a user-space process, with zero copy.
But the minus 1 would disturb such optimizations.

Plus, 63 out of 64 reads of giant file will be mis-aligned w.r.t. cache lines.

## mode of operation

```
            if (aes.Mode != CipherMode.CBC) aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
```

We don't like GCM?

It offers the possibility of a pipelined and parallelized implementation.
In contrast CBC forces sequential dependencies which prevent you
from burning all cores if that's what you'd rather.

As a separate item, I have no idea why we first test the mode,
the key size, and the padding prior to assigning them.
Just jam it in there, already!
Assign unconditionally.

## SHA-3

```
            var keys = Hkdf.DeriveKey(HashAlgorithmName.SHA384, ...
```

This appears to be a form of SHA-2, which is starting to show its age.

Consider preferring SHA-3 here, if feasible.

Also, the plural `keys` is confusing, given that we just
derived a single key.
It is especially confusing when we `.Copy(keys, 0, key, 0, ...`
The IV and salt are their own concepts; neither of those is a "key".

## negative buffer length

You have tested this, and found it to work, at least on some inputs.
So in `AesDecrypt` there is something going on which I do not yet understand.

```
                int blockBytes = (blocks - 1) * transform.InputBlockSize;
```

Why the minus 1?

Suppose `inputCount` was less than the block size, so initial `blocks` is zero.
Then we compute a negative number of bytes here?!? What?

Recommend you make an automated test suite methodically sweep through
a range of cleartext input sizes, verifying that input files of
those sizes will each be successfully roundtripped through {encrypt, deccrypt}.

## info field

In `CreateKeys`, this is weird:

```
            var info = GenerateRadomNumber(INFO_LEN);
```

There is literally no way for the decrypting end to make sense of this.

Prefer to store a constant, and verify it upon decryption.
Or more usefully, maybe store the plaintext length, and later verify it.

## versioned file signature

In `Encrypt`, please give a name to the magic number 16:

```
                var signatureChunk = new byte[rsa.KeySize / 16];
```

It is less intuitive than the `cipherMsgLength` expression.

I recommend that you roll a random GUID and use that as an initial magic number
[file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)
at the start of each encrypted file you generate.

The next one or several bytes after that should mention a version number,
so you will have the flexibility to make changes to this evolving codebase
in a way that doesn't break decryption backward compatibility.

## salt once

Within the encrypt loop we keep re-rolling a new salt, which seems odd.
It forces us to write out a new salt with each block,
which is needless overhead.
Outputting a pseudo chunk number and a MAC also seems unnecessary.
We can verify a single overall MAC after processing entire file.
Length of ciphertext file should always be K + plaintext length,
for some fixed K representing initial header and maybe trailer bytes.
Length should not become e.g. K + 1.01 × plaintextLength, that is, 1% bigger.

The negative `chunkNumber` test is less natural than just asking
if we're processing a (final!) partial block.
And I'm a little nervous about the "zero leftover bytes" case.
It's not clear that such corner cases have been thoroughly explored
by an automated test suite.

## decrypt

I like the `RequiredRead` / `Read` pair, nice and simple.
Each does One Thing well.

---

## compression

Consider performing LZMA compression prior to encryption.

By the time AES has scrambled the bits, there's no opportunity
in future to compress down English sentences within the plaintext.

## integrity

You are using some sophisticated crypto libraries that each come
with the their own assumptions, interactions, and complex options.
You had to make many choices.
Most of them appear to be good ones.
But it is *hard* to get crypto applications right,
because so much of the output is supposed to "look random",
so mistakes won't leap out at you like they would with other apps.

Consider adopting this belt-n-suspenders approach,
which is amenable to unit testing, operates entirely on plaintext and views the crypto layer as a black box.
Read `plaintext` bytes from the input file, and treat

```
{plaintext, plaintext.length, SHA3(plaintext)}
```

as the output triple you will send down to be encrypted.

Upon decrypting the crypto layer performs its various checks
and maybe throws a fatal error.
Else it updelivers such a triple, and at that higher layer
you verify the length and the hash.
Now you can be confident of integrity,
even if there was some weird bug or interaction in a lower layer.

## zero the IVs

You properly dispose of the `RSACng` and its key material -- good.

You allocate storage for several additional sensitive data structures, such as IV.
Consider using a routine like
[ZeroMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptographicoperations.zeromemory)
to [securely](https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/conference/protected-files/usenixsecurity17_slides_zhaomo_yang.pdf) zero them after use.
That prevents secret bytes from showing up in pagefile.sys,
where they can hang around and be visible to attackers.

## automated testing

I didn't notice a test suite in the GitHub repo.

This code would benefit from both unit and integration tests.
I would especially want to see methodical sweeps of input sizes,
verifying that corner cases work.

---

This codebase appears to achieve many of its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Appreciate the mention of _compression_ here. Important.